# I expect an error but I dont get what I would think

Tags: sql, oracle

I create a view

```
SQL> create view DEPT20 AS
  2  select empno AS Employee_ID_ID,ename AS Employee, deptno as Department_ID from emp
  3  where deptno = 20
  4  with check option constraint emp_dept_20;

  View created.
```

I expect to get this error

```
ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation
```

But I dont get an error I get

```
SQL> update dept20
2  set    department_ID=30
3  where  Employee='Smith';

0 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Normally I like no errors but in this one I want the error when someone tries to go outside the allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you run *this* SQL?

```
update dept20
set    department_ID=30
where  Employee='SMITH';
```

If you're using the canonical EMP table, all the employees' names are in uppercase.